# network-authentication in info.plist

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I am facing this issue when uploading build to TestFlight. I have Entitlement from apple in my development portal. Please help

> Missing Code Signing Entitlement. Use of the 'network-authentication' background mode in 'Payload/FreeWifive.app/FreeWifive' requires either the 'com.apple.developer.CaptiveNetworkPlugin' or 'com.apple.developer.networking.HotspotHelper' entitlement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this to your entitlements file should give you the proper entitlements:

```
<key>com.apple.developer.networking.HotspotHelper</key>
<true/>
```